# How do i create a backup in SQL plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, database-backups, rman

I granted the user SYSBACKUP privileges and followed the steps in this link: https://blog.toadworld.com/2017/05/29/sysbackup-and-sysdg-permissions-in-oracle-12c

However, after further analysis, it is clear that he makes a user, grants him SYSBACKUP privileges, and then restarts the database.

After further research, I have found out that I need to use something called 'Rman' but

I cannot connect to rman from my SQL plus :

```
    rman target "'/ as sysbackup'"
```

This is the error I receive

> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "rman targe..." - rest of line ignored.

And I can't find a website that shows how to create a backup, what line would i need to write that initiates a backup

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMAN don't run from SQL Plus, You need to go in a command line.

Take a look here for official documentation :
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14193/toc.htm#i771020

And you have some nice answers here about how to do : 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/163312/80688

Comment: @Annon you need to connect with SSH on the server